# Cuckoo sandbox: showing CuckooCriticalError:Please update your configuration

Tags: testing, analysis, cuckoo

I have installed cuckoo sandbox with windows7 32 bit as guest os. I have edited the "machine" and "label" field properly in "virtualbox.conf". The vm is named yo-7. But I am getting this error "`[root] CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Please update your configuration. Unable to shut 'yo-7' down or find the machine in its proper state: Timeout hit while for machine yo-7 to change status`" while executing "sudo python cuckoo.py" after displaying the following

[lib.cuckoo.core.scheduler] INFO: Using "virtualbox" machine manager

Here is the content of virtualbox.conf file

```
[virtualbox]
# Specify which VirtualBox mode you want to run your machines on.
# Can be "gui", "sdl" or "headless". Refer to VirtualBox's official
# documentation to understand the differences.
mode = gui

# Path to the local installation of the VBoxManage utility.
path = /usr/bin/VBoxManage

# Specify a comma-separated list of available machines to be used. For each
# specified ID you have to define a dedicated section containing the details
# on the respective machine. (E.g. cuckoo1,cuckoo2,cuckoo3)
machines =yo-7 

[yo-7]
# Specify the label name of the current machine as specified in your
# VirtualBox configuration.
label = yo-7

# Specify the operating system platform used by current machine
# [windows/darwin/linux].
platform = windows

# Specify the IP address of the current virtual machine. Make sure that the
# IP address is valid and that the host machine is able to reach it. If not,
# the analysis will fail.
ip = 192.168.56.101

# (Optional) Specify the snapshot name to use. If you do not specify a snapshot
# name, the VirtualBox MachineManager will use the current snapshot.
# Example (Snapshot1 is the snapshot name):
#snapshot = Win7snap1

# (Optional) Specify the name of the network interface that should be used
# when dumping network traffic from this machine with tcpdump. If specified,
# overrides the default interface specified in cuckoo.conf
# Example (vboxnet0 is the interface name):
#interface = vboxnet0

# (Optional) Specify the IP of the Result Server, as your virtual machine sees it.
# The Result Server will always bind to the address and port specified in cuckoo.conf,
# however you could set up your virtual network to use NAT/PAT, so you can specify here 
# the IP address for the Result Server as your machine sees it. If you don't specify an
# address here, the machine will use the default value from cuckoo.conf.
# NOTE: if you set this option you have to set result server IP to 0.0.0.0 in cuckoo.conf.
# Example:
#resultserver_ip = 192.168.56.1

# (Optional) Specify the port for the Result Server, as your virtual machine sees it.
# The Result Server will always bind to the address and port specified in cuckoo.conf,
# however you could set up your virtual network to use NAT/PAT, so you can specify here
# the port for the Result Server as your machine sees it. If you don't specify a port
# here, the machine will use the default value from cuckoo.conf.
# Example:
#resultserver_port = 2042

# (Optional) Set your own tags. These are comma separated and help to identify
# specific VMs. You can run samples on VMs with tag you require.
#tags = windows_xp_sp3,32_bit,acrobat_reader_6
```

Comment: Nevermind I solved It...Its because of privilege issues,i installed the vm and cuckoo as root

Comment: any idea how to do integration in java with cuckoo sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Your possible problem is in the ip, you must change maybe to 192.168.56.1, it's the ip by  default that virtuaboxl assign to virtual machine other thing it's the internal ip of the host then it's 192.168.1.10x (1 or 2). I hope explain me well, it may be little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

the label should be the virtual machine's name, not the username in the vm system